# using SCSS values from another file

Tags: css, sass

Super simple question, which i cant find answer for some reason...

Fist time using scss.
I have app wide styling in one file, lets say typography.scss
which has, among other things colors.

```
/* type */
$text-light: #ffffff;
$text-light-gray: #b4b6b7;
$text-dark: #000000;
```

and in other file i have `use` like

```
@use "../../styles/typography";
```

but i dont get how i use just the values?

```
color: ???   //needs to be #000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use the variable you declared, by name. Like this:

```
color: $text-dark
```

Comment: Thank you! bit ashamed now, been doing development for years (not web tho) how did i not try that?!? eitherway, cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
@import "../../styles/typography" 

.your-class { 
   color: $text-dark;
}
```

Also I recommend moving your colors to a _variables.scss